# Error al compilar Android

Tags: android, genexus

```
Genexus17u6
c#
Android
```

Tengo una app Android que generaba perfecto y ahora al volver a generarla, me da errores en la compilación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Miro el path en mi disco y no tengo esos archivos (porque la carpeta 17.6.7 no existe) :

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/GeneXus/GeneXus17_U6/Android/m2Repository/com/genexus/CoreExternalObjects/17.6.7/CoreExternalObjects-17.6.7.pom
```

Si tengo la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hice rebuild all, reinstale SDK y borre la carpeta mobile, sigue todo igual dando ese error.

**¿Qué puede estar fallando? ¿Porqué pide una versión que no tengo en mi pc?** Como dato adicional aviso que tengo varias versiones de GX instaladas en mi pc.

**Actualización de información:**

Ingresé en gradle Options --info

Intenta obtener varios recursos online y no lo logra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acualización de información 2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La version 17.6.1 se corresponde a v17u6 release. La version que busca, 17.6.7 se corresponde al ultimo HF (HotFix de v17u6). 
Te recomiendo que verifiques bien que version estas ejecutando? y si es el ultimo HF del u6, volver a instalarlo, para que copie los archivos faltantes.

Comment: Si tengo el HotFix v17u6 instalado. Pero no copia archivos faltantes, su instalación es simplemente sobreescribir 5 archivos que incluye el zip en la carpeta de instalción GX. Dejo imagen del contenido del HF.